# android app ressource location

Tags: android, api, twitter

I'm trying to use twitter's API for Android, it asks me to add something to my app's ressources, in which file should I paste it in ? Or should I create a new file in the 'res' folder ?

Comment: *" it asks me to add something"*...would you mind sharing what *something* is? Might make a difference.

Comment: like written on the post bellow, it's the api key thing...
thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add your API key and secret to your **string** resources.

```
<resources>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

This can be found under *app* -> *res* -> *values* -> *strings.xml*